# Emberjs tests hang when running through CLI

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-data, phantomjs, teaspoon

My Ember test suite is timing out when I run it through the command line. I've tracked this down and it's due to `ajaxComplete` not firing for an AJAX request that is kicked off through a call to `visit`, but this same request fires the complete event fine when running through the browser.

The `ajaxComplete` event triggers a call to Ember's `decrementAjaxPendingRequests` and when that's not called it will continually spin during the `wait` method as `Test.pendingAjaxRequests` requests is not 0. You can see that here:

```
    function wait(app, value) {
      return Test.promise(function(resolve) {
        // If this is the first async promise, kick off the async test
        if (++countAsync === 1) {
          Test.adapter.asyncStart();
        }

        // Every 10ms, poll for the async thing to have finished
        var watcher = setInterval(function() {
          console.log("watcher tick");
          // 1. If the router is loading, keep polling
          var routerIsLoading = !!app.__container__.lookup('router:main').router.activeTransition;
          if (routerIsLoading) { 
            return; 
          }

          // 2. If there are pending Ajax requests, keep polling
          if (Test.pendingAjaxRequests) { 
            console.log("PENDING AJAX REQUESTS: ", Test.pendingAjaxRequests, " - RETURNING");
            return;
          }

          // 3. If there are scheduled timers or we are inside of a run loop, keep polling
          if (run.hasScheduledTimers() || run.currentRunLoop) {
            return;
         }

          if (Test.waiters && Test.waiters.any(function(waiter) {
            var context = waiter[0];
            var callback = waiter[1];
            return !callback.call(context);
          })) { 
            return;
          }
          // Stop polling
          clearInterval(watcher);


          // If this is the last async promise, end the async test
          if (--countAsync === 0) {
            Test.adapter.asyncEnd();
          }

          // Synchronously resolve the promise
          run(null, resolve, value);
        }, 10);
      });

    }
```

The AJAX request in question is from a model hook in one of my routes and it's a simple `return this.store.find('model_name')`. I'm using sinon.js to fake this request out and I'm seeing it return correctly if I put a `then` clause on that find call, but it still is not firing it's `ajaxComplete` event.

Here is my stack:

- Ember: 1.7.1
- Ember-Data: 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a
- Teaspoon (My test runner): 0.8.0
- jQuery: 1.10.2
- PhantomJS (CLI Test Runner): 1.9.7 && 1.8.2

Does anybody know if there is any open issue for this or what specific part of the stack could be causing it? I'm at a loss for where to go from here.

Comment: Woah, this might not be the source of the problem, but you should probably update PhantomJS. 1.8.2 is pretty old. 1.9.8 is the newest and 2.0 around the corner.

Comment: I actually have the same issue & for what it's worth: https://twitter.com/stefanpenner/status/522091567637868544

Comment: @James_1x0 Woah, did not know this was a thing. Any suggestions?

Comment: For the record I've updated PhantomJS to 1.9.7 and this issue still persists.

Comment: Are you using mocha by any chance?

Comment: @PatsyIssa No I'm using Teaspoon and QUnit.

Comment: running into same issue, ever find a solution?

Comment: @flylib I ended up commenting out those tests unfortunately. I couldn't find a solution. Huge bummer. Phantomjs sucks.

Comment: my issue was I had a disconnectOutlet for an outlet modal in my route that used a parentView of application and for some unexplainable reason, that made Test.pendingAjaxRequests get stuck at 1 and never finish as ajaxComplete never got called